# How do I do the equivalent of "myClass[].class" with ArrayList<myClass>?

Tags: java, android

I'm using the GSON library and calling the fromJson() method:
http://google-gson.googlecode.com/svn/tags/1.2.3/docs/javadocs/com/google/gson/Gson.html

My old code:

```
String s = new GsonBuilder().create().fromJson(responseString,myClass[].class);
```

Works fine, but I'm moving the collection from an array to an ArrayList and I can't figure out the syntax to use to pass the type to this method. If I understand correctly the existing code is passing the type (an array of myClass objects) to the method, which it then creates from the JSON response.

But I have tried all the syntax combinations I can think of and I'm stumped for how to do what I thought would look like this:

```
String s = new GsonBuilder().create().fromJson(responseString, ArrayList<myClass>.class );
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Gson, you use a `TypeToken` to represent a generic type. Note the `{}` in there; it's necessary because it creates a subclass of `TypeToken` with the generic type information.

```
List<MyClass> list = new Gson().fromJson(responseString, 
    new TypeToken<ArrayList<MyClass>>(){}.getType());
```

Comment: I replaced MyClass with my actual class name, and it compiles ok, but at runtime throws a ClassCastException: java.util.LinkedList  I'm not using a LinkedList in my own code, so not sure what that exception means is wrong.

Comment: @Ollie C: Hmm... try using `new TypeToken<List<MyClass>>` instead of specifying `ArrayList` and see what happens.

Comment: Same thing unfortunately. I've worked around it by pulling the JSON results into an array and then copy into an ArrayList, but would be great to have a better solution that that, it's kinda ugly. Thx

Comment: @Ollie C: I'm guessing you're trying to assign the result to something of type `ArrayList`... you need to assign it to something that's just of type `List`, because Gson returns a `LinkedList` rather than an `ArrayList` for lists. It's also generally a best practice to refer to objects by their interface when possible, and that's true for `List` in particular. You shouldn't usually care what kind of `List` it is exactly.

Comment: Ah, ok. If it's going to return a LinkedList, I'll still have to copy items across to an ArrayList, so I'll just leave my array copy code in there anyway. Thx

Answer (score 0):

From the [API docs](http://google-gson.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/gson/docs/javadocs/com/google/gson/Gson.html#fromJson%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Class%29):

> This method deserializes the specified
>   Json into an object of the specified
>   class. It is not suitable to use if
>   the specified class is a generic type
>   since it will not have the generic
>   type information because of the Type
>   Erasure feature of Java. Therefore,
>   this method should not be used if the
>   desired type is a generic type.

Why do you need an arraylist? It seems that it's only ever used internally.

Comment: Why not add the part that said `For the cases when the object is of generic type, invoke fromJson(String, Type).`

Comment: -1 This makes it sound like you can't do this in Gson, when you can quite easily.

Answer (score 0):

The generic type is erased in Runtime, so you can only use ArrayList.class.

I don't know how this works for json